# How to show a Message Box when the value of a formula cell in an array is changed from 0 to 1

Tags: excel, vba, messagebox

I have a spreadsheet table for data entry. When certain criteria on a line in the table is met, I want to trigger a Message Box as a reminder for the user to do something.

First, I wrote a formula in another column of the table which would return either a 1 or a 0 based on the data the user entered in that line of the table. This worked fine (FYI, for rows with no data entered yet, the formula returns a 0)

The part that is an issue is getting a message box to trigger when any of the cells in this new column turn from 0 to 1. I want the message to appear, the user reads it and clicks okay, and then the message box to go away and not appear again. I only want it to appear again when another line of data is entered which meets the criteria and turns that lines cell from a 0 to 1.

But when I tried to write some VBA code (See below) using a 'Private Sub Worksheet Calculate()' I quickly found that because the cell value remained 1 after I clicked ok on the message box, the message box was immediately triggered again, in a loop. Note, i wrote this code for 1 cell in mind, but what I really want is for this to apply to the whole 'W' column:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
 If Range("W1") = 1 Then
  MsgBox "Send email to author"
 End If
End Sub
```

I also then tried the following code based on someone elses post. This only ended up displaying the message every time I changed something on the worksheet, even if it didn't effect the value in column W. Again note, I really want it to apply to the whole of column W.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
   Dim target As Range
    Set target = Range("W1")
    If Not Intersect(Range("W1"), Range("W1")) Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Send email to author"
    End If
End Sub
```

I've gone as far as my understanding of VBA will take me, which is not far at all, so maybe someone can show me where I am going wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: have a look at the Application.EnableEvents property:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.enableevents

just make sure you turn them back on at the end.

Comment: So, if W1 = 0, W2 = 0, the user inputs something in A1 causing W1 to become 1 -> MessageBox. Then the user inputs something else, which causes W2 to become 1 -> Should the MessageBox come up here? After that, the user enters something in A1, so W1 = 0 -> No MessageBox here. After that, a change in A1 causes W1 to become 1 again -> Should a MessageBox appear?

Comment: Hi z32a7ul, you are on the right track. When data is entered in A1, A2, A37, Awhatever I want the respective W cell to become a 1 if the criteria is met. So to answer your first question, yes the message should come up when W2 becomes 1. As for your second question, the nature of the table means nobody should be changing data. However, if they did want to go back for whatever reason, it would be best if it didn't show when it got changed back to 0, but when it became 1 again then it should show the message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the main point is that you need to save the previous state of W. One option is a global variable in VBA but that is not saved with the workbook, and any reset will delete its value. Therefore you should make some place for it e.g. in column X.

If W is the current state of 0/1 - shall we show a MsgBox, and X is the previous state, then you can use the below code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Worksheet_Calculate_ColW
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate_ColW()
    Dim wRange As Range: Set wRange = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("W:W"), Me.UsedRange)
    Dim xRange As Range: Set xRange = wRange.Offset(0, 1)
    Dim wValues() As Variant: wValues = wRange.Value
    Dim xValues() As Variant: xValues = xRange.Value
    Dim r As Long: For r = LBound(wValues, 1) To UBound(wValues, 1)
        If wValues(r, 1) <> xValues(r, 1) Then ' Changed
            If wValues(r, 1) = 1 Then          ' Changed to 1
                MsgBox "Send email to author: " & wRange.Cells(r, 1).Address & " has changed to 1"
            End If
            xRange.Cells(r, 1) = wValues(r, 1) ' Do not show up next time
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I have extracted this feature into function `Worksheet_Calculate_ColW` because `Worksheet_Calculate` may have other tasks as well. You may want to rename it to something more meaningful along with `wRange`, `xRange` and the other variables considering their semantic context.

Note: Although a cell in column X is changed by the function, which may cause a recalculation and a nested call to this function, the next time the values of X and W in the same row will be the same, therefore an endless loop is not a real threat.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion and code, that has done the job and I have adapted this to use in the spreadsheet. I will implement this for a week or so and hopefully i don't have any issues with it. Thanks very much again

Answer (score 1):

Only run the code when the user updates a value in the table.

This is done using the `Worksheet_Change` event.  The cell/cells being changed are reference by `Target` in the procedure arguments.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim TableRange As Range
        Set TableRange = .Range("B3:H10")
        
        'Column 9 is column I.
        If Not Intersect(Target, TableRange) Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Send email, the value of " & .Cells(Target.Row, 9).Address & " is " & .Cells(Target.Row, 9)
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub
```

Further reading:
[With Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement)

*Edit:*
If you want a message to appear when the calculated value changes then you can capture the old value in the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event and compare it in the `Worksheet_Change` event.

```
Private OldValue As String '<Place at the top of the module.

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim TableRange As Range
        Set TableRange = .Range("B3:H10")
        
        'Column 9 is column I.
        If Not Intersect(Target, TableRange) Is Nothing Then
            If .Cells(Target.Row, 9) <> OldValue Then
                MsgBox "Send email, the value of " & .Cells(Target.Row, 9).Address & _
                    " has changed from " & OldValue & " to " & .Cells(Target.Row, 9)
            End If
        End If
    End With
    
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim TableRange As Range
        Set TableRange = .Range("B3:H10")
        
        'Column 9 is column I.
        If Not Intersect(Target, TableRange) Is Nothing Then
            OldValue = .Cells(Target.Row, 9)
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. Can you confirm that this code will work if the cell is a formula cell? It's just whenever I have tried to use Worksheet_Change it has never worked if the cell value is determined using a formula, rather than text

Comment: No, it doesn't work on a cell with a formula.  But, the user enters data which updates the formula so the code watches for the user entering data in the table and then returns the value of the formula on the row that the user updated.

Comment: Hi Darren, unfortunately I don't think this approach is going to work. This is because the formula is not solely reading the inputted data on that line, it is also somewhat dependent on the data from a varying range of lines below it. This is why ive used the formula in the first place, just to simply the issue. So I really just want the W column to be read for changes after data is inputted. Thanks